# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, ant, noclassdeffounderror

Windows 7 32 bit.Java 6. Ant 1.9.2.

I am trying to run jar file that contains main class. Let's see diretory structure of my SwarmMentics.jar:

```
- gov.usgs.swarm.Swarm.class
- net.n3.....
- nz.org....
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

As you guess main class is gov.usgs.swarm.Swarm.class. The file MANIFEST.MF is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: gov.usgs.swarm.Swarm
```

Whatever I run  I always receive exception:

```
Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gov/usgs/swarm/Swarm
Caused by : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException gov.usgs.swarm.Swarm
```

I searched the Internet and and I don't have any ideas.

**EDIT:**
I want to run main class `gov.usgs.swarm.Swarm` which is in jar SwarmMentics.jar.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `java -jar SwarmMentics.jar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your package name seems wrong.

Your jar contains:

```
gov.usgs.swarm.Swarm.class
```

while Java complains of:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/usgs/swarm/Swarm
```

Comment: This was typed by me manually and I made a mistake. Can you give one cool java command to run that.

Comment: The best I try is `java -cp . gov.usgs.swarm.Swarm`. And I receive just that error

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the tool should do. Could you please be more specific ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I use ANT 1.9.2 at windows 7 32 bit, java6

Comment: How do you run it ? Command line or Ant ? Does it work when you invoke it inside your IDE ?

Comment: I run it via command-line. I can't use IDE. Now I try `java -jar SwarmMentics.jar` and new error is : `ClassNotFoundException com/jgoodies/looks/plastic/Plastic3DLookAndFeel`

Comment: That means you don't have `com.jgoodies` in your classpath: `java -classpath jgoodies-looks-<version>.jar -jar SwarmMentics.jar`